# Relative coordinates using get and set axes methods in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

One way to control where in the `figure` object a new `axes` is supposed to go is by using the `add_axes` method. This method takes in a list or tuple of 4 values which represent [left, bottom, width, height] where all quantities are in fractions of figure witdth and height. For example:

```
import matplotlib
fig = plt.figure()
fig.add_axes([0.1,0.2,0.3, 0.4])
```

Adds a new `axes` object in the specified relative coordinates. If I then go on to try to extract these coordinates:

```
fig.axes[0].get_position()
```

The result is a `Bbox` object:

```
>>> Bbox([[0.1, 0.2], [0.4, 0.6000000000000001]])
```

The issue is I don't want a Bbox object, I want to get my relative coordinates back so that I can operate on them using `set_axes` (which takes in left, bottom width and height again) to relocate my axes.

Is there anyway to convert the `Bbox` to the format that I need, or perhaps to force the `get_position()` method to spit out relative coordinates like so?

```
[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The figure's [`add_axes`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_axes) method takes as argument a `rect`

> `add_axes(*args, **kwargs)`
>   Add an axes at position rect `[left, bottom, width, height]`

`axes.get_position()`
returns a `BBox` object. This has, as seen from [its documentation](https://matplotlib.org/devel/transformations.html#matplotlib.transforms.BboxBase.bounds), a property

> `bounds`
>   (property) Returns `(x0, y0, width, height)`.

Hence you want to call

```
ax.get_position().bounds
```

To obtain the the boundaries of the rectangle of the axes.

Comment: Yup. That does it.

Comment: `get_position().bounds` returns `(xmin, ymin, width, height)` and `get_position().get_points()` returns numpy array `[[xmin, ymin], [xmax, ymax]]`